# does the server being closer to the user decrease the latency?

Tags: networking, server, cloud

To what extent the server being closer to the user decrease the latency between the user and the service and help the overall experience ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends greatly on what you mean by "closer."

If the two devices are on the same wire, the latency is negligible since the signal travels in copper at about one-third the speed of light. The latency due to distance can be calculated based the distances of the various media in the path.  Moving devices closer, from the perspective of cabling distance, depending on the distance, may have a noticeable difference in latency.

Having multiple devices (switches, routers, etc.) in between the two will increase the latency more due to serialization/de-serialization, encapsulation/de-encapsulation, switching, buffering, etc. delays.  This is much more complex, and probably has a more significant increase in the latency.